# Should structuring an academic text with the help of questions be avoided?

Tags: style, academic-writing, resources

In an academic writing course some years ago I remember being told that when writing, for instance, a journal article in English, one should usually avoid structuring one's text with the help of explicit questions, something like:

> In the previous section we saw that the values of X are particularly high when considering Y, suggesting that... Blablaa. Bla. Could this be interpreted as a result of Z?
>
> And then I go on and answer my own question.

Or something like:

> X's statement does seem credible in light of Y. This interpretation, however, poses another question: Why is it the case that Z, if ...?
>
> And here I start to build the answer

Are there actually some stylistic guidelines that would recommend avoiding these kinds of structures? Does anyone know about a resource where something like this would be mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking as a professor and author of several academic papers; I would avoid it.

Rhetorical questions are a technique we use in classrooms to generate interest or debate among students. That is a form of "entertainment" and entertainment is NOT the goal of a paper, it is reporting your research and conclusions, and you should not present any ambiguous or "teaser" lines in the process.

The reader cannot answer questions. You are not writing a mystery novel! This may seem "dry" but that is what is expected. To rewrite your text:

> In the previous section we saw that the values of X are particularly high when considering Y, suggesting [a,b,c]. We will now show this behavior can be interpreted as a result of [d].
>
> Thus X's statement does seem credible in light of Y. To complete the argument, we must show that [e] holds, to justify why [f] holds.

In other words, it is fine to tell the reader in a 'summary line' what you are about to more formally prove or argue. Typically you can reword your questions to provide a summary statement of what is to come instead of the question, which is really the point of the question.

I certainly would not put a ban on all rhetorical questions in academic papers, but for **students** I would not allow them at all. Learn to write without them; stick to the facts and presenting your work, keep emotional appeal out of it. That is what is expected; at least in my scientific fields.

In other fields where I have read few academic papers (e.g. psychology or history or law) I could be swayed if shown several other highly quoted *recently published* papers (e.g. in the last 20 years) that make heavy use of rhetorical questions.

But still, IMO you can avoid them and make a stronger paper. A rhetorical question is **always** an introduction to a discussion that can be rewritten to serve better as a summary statement imparting a fact about what comes next, and typically the statement will be shorter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add anything to Amadeus's answer, which is perfect when looking at an academic paper and gives the reasons why the rhetorical approach doesn't work.

I notice you've also mentioned a journal article, which could take us into something of a grey area. No journal will have a problem with information presented as an academic paper, and if you're writing for journals in a generic sense this would be the way to go.

The exception would be if you were writing for a specific journal that you knew used a less formal style - in this case presenting the information in a way that's closer to entertainment might work better. In this case, the stylistic guidelines would be based on previous articles in that particular journal - you could also ask whether they have a specific house style.

Comment: Note that when an academic says *journal article,* they are almost certainly talking about an academic paper published in an academic journal – which is *the*o way of publishing in most fields.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends who the audience is -- if by "academic text" you mean textbook or supplement to educational materials, then questions may be great!

Often in PlainLanguage, they advice question-headings in first person (as the reader has a question in mind), and then answer using 2nd person to mean the reader.

https://www.plainlanguage.gov/guidelines/organize/add-useful-headings/

In the [PlainLanguage.Gov Training](https://www.plainlanguage.gov/training/create-your-own-class/) area, they have a PPTX that I adapted and used when I taught technical writing, as I found them to be great guidelines for addressing non-expert users without talking down to them.